# Modify jQuery load script to replace two divs instead of one

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have:

```
<!-- home.php -->
<div id='leftColumn'>
    <input class='showVLANBtn'>
</div>
<div id='subHeader'>
    <div id='pageLogo'>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='page'>
    <div id='subPage'>
        <!-- misc. content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I have jQuery:

```
$("input.showVLANBtn").click(function(){
    $('#page')
        .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')
        .load('televlans.php #page')
        .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Upon clicking the `.showVLANBtn` , home.php:`#page` is replaced with televlans.php:`#page`.

I want to modify the above jQuery to also replace home.php:`#pageLogo` with televlans.php:`#pageLogo` when `.showVLANBtn` is clicked.

**I figured it out.  If anyone is interested, below is my working jQuery**

```
$("input.showVLANBtn").click(function(){
    $('#page', function(){
        $('#pageLogo')
            .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')
            .load
            ('televlans.php #pageLogo')
            .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    })
        .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')
        .load
        ('televlans.php #pageLoaded')
        .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you want to load those 2 files separately or concurrently ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, Is my answer what you are looking for?

Comment: If possible , can post `html` / "another `div` on `home.php`" ? ; describe other data within `televlans.php` which would be added to second `div` at `home.php` ? Thanks

Comment: just updated my question to be as clear as possible.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: negative review?  What should I have done differently???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try this:

```
$('#page')
    .add('#another_div')        //<--- add this line
    .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')
    .load('televlans.php #page')
    .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
```

[jQuery add() docs](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Or

```
$('#page,#another_div')
    ...
```

[jQuery multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

From [.load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) , appear method is "shorthand" for `$.get(url, data, success)` ; fetching the full contents of `url` , though only setting `html` of provided selector . The contents could be further filtered at the `complete` callback ; to perform other tasks with the returned data , utilizing different selectors , different portions of returned `data`.

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when `textStatus`
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), `.load()` sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data.

Try

```
$("input.showVLANBtn").click(function(){
    $('#page')
        .delay(200).fadeOut('slow')
        .load('televlans.php #page'
        , function(data) {
          // `#page-2` : `other div` at `televlans.php`
          // `#anotherDiv` : `another div` at `home.php`
          $(data).filter("#page-2").appendTo("#anotherDiv");
        })
        .hide().delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ckLv2eub/

Comment: I solved my problem, your solution was closest to what was needed.  See my edit for what I did to solve this issue..